# React — Requesting data using Fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to get some data from an API using Fetch without success. For some reason the request is failing and I am not able to render the data... as I am quite new to React and Fetch I am not sure where the error is. Is it something to do with the way I am requesting the API?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Data />
  }
}


class Data extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      requestFailed: false,
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() { // Executes after mouting
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then(response => {
        if (!request.ok) {
          throw Error("Network request failed.")
        }
        return response
      })
      .then(d => d.json())
      .then(d => {
        this.setState({
          data: d
      })
    }, () => {
      this.setState({
        requestFailed: true
      })
    })
  }
  
  
  render() {
    
    if(this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Request failed.</p>
    if(!this.state.data) return <p>Loading</p>
    
    return (
      <h1>{this.state.data.results[0].gender}</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/diegooriani/pen/mMyyaM?editors=0010)

Comment: Can you be sure the fetch failed? You should add a .catch() to get the error. e.g. `fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then(response => {
        if (!request.ok) {
          throw Error("Network request failed.")
        }
        return response
      }).catch((error) => { console.log(error);})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the [GITHUB docs](https://github.com/github/fetch#json), you can implement the fetch like

```
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then((d) =>  {
    console.log('parsed json', d)
    this.setState({
          data: d
    });
  }).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
    this.setState({
        requestFailed: true
      })
  })
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaJXxv?editors=0010)**

Comment: Thank you Shubham for the solution and the link. I just realised I was looking into a different documentation.

Comment: No problem , Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

fetch method should be

```
fetch('your_url')
  .then (  
  response => {  
    if (response.status !== 200) {   
      return 'Error. Status Code: ' +  response.status   
    }
    response.json().then(result => console.log(result)) // do sth with data 
  }  
)
  .catch(function(err) {  
  console.log('Opps Error', err)  
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: np mate, I posted this simple snippet for you to easy to define where the "result" come and you can do whatever with it, console to log out those data is the convenience way I used to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with

```
.then(response => {
    if (!request.ok) {
      throw Error("Network request failed.")
    }
    return response
  })
```

There's no **request** object that has the property **ok**. Maybe you mean to check **response.ok** ?

```
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error("Network request failed.")
    }
    return response
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.